# AddressAlreadyInUse Exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new in learning C# Service Client Application.
I made one project, the problem is that whenever I run it it shows the following exception:

> Address Already in use Exception:
>   HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/6c2d8437-020f-4267-b93b-450ef3546b04/ because TCP port 80 is being used by another application.

But the same project works fine in my sister's laptop.I don't know what is the reason but I am somehow sure that there is nothing wrong with the project.

Comment: Is the `Net.TCP Port Sharing Service` disabled? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get WCF Exception "HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/MyService/"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333945/why-do-i-get-wcf-exception-http-could-not-register-url-http-80-myservice)

Comment: Net.TCP Port Sharing Service

Answer (score 0):

Your port 80 is in use. Another application on your computer is using it.

Maybe you are running a webserver?

If you are, maybe your project should be hosted there instead. If not, you can simply use another port.

Comment: <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/webshopservice/Cwebshop/" />  This is the base address for my service , then why it is saying 80 port is in use

Comment: Net.TCP Port Sharing Service is also disabled

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that Skype was running on this port.After ending Skype process,the exception disappeared